# VBA- How to start pasting to a certain cell

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a code that chooses a certain code copies its row and pastes it into another sheet. I need to make each code word start pasting into a certain cell in the new sheet. Ex: for the code PP to paste into A11, A12,A13...etc and FA to paste into A23,A24...etc.

[image: Data Table]

This is the code so far:

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
 Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long

Set ws1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5")
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "PP" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Get new last row value
        LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

   ElseIf ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "FA" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

ElseIf ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "IA" Then
    ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

ElseIf ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "P" Then
    ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

 ElseIf ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "PR" Then
    ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

ElseIf ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "CK" Then
    ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    LRow2 = LRow2 + 1

 End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? It's a little unclear

Answer (score 0):

one of the may ways you can do it is the following

- set a specific range related to every code

  I'd use a `Select Case` construct instead of a `If ...Then... Else If ...End IF` one, since the former is much clearer for checking a value against different possible ones
- count the number of already not empty cells in specific range and start pasting values from the cell below

as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long

    Set ws1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5")
    LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    For i = 2 To LRow1
        Select Case ws1.Cells(i, 1)
            Case "PP"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A11:A22") 'PP codes related range is A11:A22 in worksheet ws2  
            Case "FA"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A23:A34") 'PP codes related range is A23:A34 in worksheet ws2   
            Case "IA"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A35:A46") ' and so on
            Case "P"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A47:A58")
            Case "PR"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A59:A70")
            Case "CK"
                Set rng = ws2.Range("A71:A82")
            Case Else
                Set rng = Nothing
        End Select

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            LRow2 = WorksheetFunction.Count(rng) ' count the not empty cell in set range
            rng(LRow2 + 1).Resize(, 4).Value = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 2), ws1.Cells(i, 5)).Value ' copy values only
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would change the `Select Case ws1.Cells(i, 1)` to `Select Case ws1.Cells(i,1).Value` so you are explicitly referencing the Cell's value instead of the `Range` object.

Comment: Any Idea why the code is skipping the intermediate values, say I have a table with three "PP", it will only copy and paste the first and the last data.